# Excel VBA Editor UI Issues when on 2nd / 3rd screen

Tags: excel, user-interface, ide, vba

Just wondered if anyone has encountered this same issue and found a fix

[image]

I don't have this issue when the VBA editor is on the screen of my surface, but thats tiny, and I prefer to work with my monitors.

The odd thing is that the code at the top doesn't have this issue.

Note: I haven't checked other Vb applications

Comment: Weird. I'd imagine this is a bug with your version of Excel and will need reporting to Microsoft rather than here.

Comment: This is really strange. What happens if you unplug the 2. and the 3. screen? How are they connected to the pc?

Comment: @Tom Yea I know, but I figured I would put it here and eventually add the solution so that other people can reference it

Comment: @Vityata miniDP -> DP